# first object of arraylist becomes null, cant seem to figure out why

Tags: java, list, arraylist

So here is the issue. my concatinate function for intervals seems to be turning the first value passed into it to null, and i cant for the love of god figure out why.

```
public static ArrayList<Intervals> ConcatinateIntervals(ArrayList<Intervals> intervals) {
    ArrayList<Intervals> concatinatedIntervals = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i<intervals.size(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<intervals.size(); j++){
            if(i==j){
               continue;
            }
            if(intervals.get(i).getMax() < intervals.get(j).getMin() || intervals.get(i).getMin()>intervals.get(j).getMax()){
            Intervals interval = intervals.get(i).Clone();
            concatinatedIntervals.add(interval);
            continue;
            }
            // 1
            if(intervals.get(i).getMin() < intervals.get(j).getMin() && intervals.get(i).getMax()<intervals.get(j).getMax()){
                Intervals interval = new Intervals(intervals.get(i).getMin(),intervals.get(j).getMax());
                concatinatedIntervals.add(interval);
                break;
            }//2
            if(intervals.get(i).getMin() < intervals.get(j).getMin() && intervals.get(i).getMax()>intervals.get(j).getMax()){
                Intervals interval = intervals.get(i).Clone();
                concatinatedIntervals.add(interval);
                break;
            }//3
            if(intervals.get(i).getMin() < intervals.get(j).getMax() && intervals.get(i).getMax()>intervals.get(j).getMax()){
                Intervals interval = new Intervals(intervals.get(j).getMin(),intervals.get(i).getMax());
                concatinatedIntervals.add(interval);
                break;
            }//4
            if(intervals.get(i).getMin() > intervals.get(j).getMin() && intervals.get(i).getMax()<intervals.get(j).getMax()){
                Intervals interval = new Intervals(intervals.get(j).getMin(),intervals.get(j).getMax());
                concatinatedIntervals.add(interval);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //removes all duplicates
    Object[] st = concatinatedIntervals.toArray();
    for (Object s : st) {
        if (concatinatedIntervals.indexOf(s) != concatinatedIntervals.lastIndexOf(s)) {
            concatinatedIntervals.remove(concatinatedIntervals.lastIndexOf(s));
         }
    }

    return concatinatedIntervals;
}
```

It should be returning a 3 intervals of 10, 100 200,300 and 400,500. but I seem to be getting `null`. Cant figure out where I'm going wrong. please help.

The idea is that for any input of intervals its going to return a list of intervals either 10-500 og 10-100, 200-300, 400-500 and if any are duplicates its supposed to strip that away and concatinate so they become one larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean the `ArrayList` returned is not null but *contains null elements* (`Interval`s), since the reference to `concatinatedIntervals` is only ever set equal to a constructor call and thus cannot be null. You implemented your own cloning method apparently, as you write `Clone()` instead of `clone()`. The only places where `Interval`s are added to the list add either references that were assigned the result of a constructor call in the previous line (and thus cannot be null) or add the result of a call to `Clone()`. Thus the `Clone()` method is the only obvious suspect.

Have you tried stepping through execution of your code line-by-line with a debugger, checking the values of all the `Interval`s added?

Comment: Thank you! the problem was indid the Clone method beeing invalid and such returning an null object to the ArrayList.